# How to insert the data from the same table which is in another instance using ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Need your suggestion on insert the data from the same table which is in another instance using ORACLE SQL,but I have different case,explained below.

We have two instance A and B,and table Test exist in both the instance with same structure,but table in the **Instance A** doesn't have any data,wherein Table in **Instance B** has got some data.
We want to copy the data from **Instance B** to **instance A**,but ID from **instance A** be should be populated with the **ID A11** ,not with the id from the **instance B** table.
Please note: **We want to update this time at the time of inserting the data to the table in the Instance A** not after that.

```
**Instance A**                  **Instance B**
Table Test                   Table Test                         
ID  column1 column2       ID    column1   column2       
                          A12   500        600              
                          A12   500        600               
                          A12   700        750               
                          A12   500        600      
                          A12   500        600
```

Results in the **instance A** after copying the data from **instance B** should be as below

```
ID   column1    column2
A11  500          600
A11  500          600
A11  700          750
A11  500          600
A11  500          600
```

Please let us know how can proceed to achieve this.Your inputs on this will be highly appreciated.

[image: clearer table structure of the tables given above]

Answer (score 0):

What do you call an "Instance"? Is it a different user in the same database? A different database? Something else?

If the former, user A should grant INSERT to user B, and - connected as B - you'd

```
insert into a.test (id, column1, column2)
select 'A11', column1, column2
from test;
```

If the later, you'd create a database link from B to A and (connected as B)

```
insert into test@dbl_a (id, column1, column2)
select 'A11', column1, column2
from test;
```

If none of above, the answer might depend on what the "instance" is.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply @Littlefoot,sorry forgot to mention -its the same user but different database.
In my real database the table test has got more than 100 columns,so do I need to specify all the columns,or this there any way out that I can eliminate this effort.

Comment: Another database >>> use a database link; no doubt in that. As you want to do it in one go, you'll have to specify all 100 columns and put 'A11' into the ID column. Otherwise, if the tables are the same, you could have used `insert into test@dbl_a select * from test` and then `update test@dbl_a set id = 'A11'` but you said that you don't want to do that. So - no shortcuts, sorry.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help@ Littlefoot,will try the first method you said.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is generate a bunch of insert statements for each line of B, and then manually call them in the A database. Something like

```
SELECT 'Insert into test (id, column1, column2) values (''A11'', ' || b.column1 || ', ' || b.column2 || ');'
FROM test b;
```

This will generate a bunch of insert statements that would look like

```
Insert into test (id, column1, column2) values ('A11', 500, 600);
```

And then you can manually invoke those insert statements in your other database.

**EDIT**

Based on your comment that *table Test has 100s of columns*, it might be best then to use [data pump export](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_export.htm) `expdp` and [data pump import](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_import.htm) `impdp`. With those utilities, you can specify to export only the data of your test table, and then you can import into your other instance.

Make sure to include for `expdp` the arguments `TABLES=Test CONTENT=DATA_ONLY` and for the `impdp` the arguments `TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=APPEND`

Comment: Thanks for your reply @plasmaTonic.But concerns here is My test table has got more than 100 columns,so would be difficult to generate the bunch of insert statements.Is there any way we can insert without mentioning the columns